# Alert 3 doesn't show up when I run ajaxRequest.open

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my AJAX script, I put in some alerts to see where the problem lies, here is my script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function positionUpdate(var1, var2){
        alert ("1");
        var queryString = "?var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2;
        alert ("2");
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "position_update.php" + queryString, true);
        alert ("3");
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
        alert ("4");
    }
</script>
```

Alert 3 doesn't show up when I run it so it looks like the problem is with this line but I don't know what it is:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "position_update.php" + queryString, true);
```

Thanks, Stanni

Comment: does ajaxRequest exist and is open() a method of it?  Debugging javascript is a lot easier if you have a tool like Firebug installed.

Comment: You should also look into using the debugger keyword.  It will break into the javascript at that line and can help you walk through the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the ajaxRequest object yet.  At that point, it's still undefined.

You'll need to have this first:

```
try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see, how would I go about initializing it? Sorry, i am new to javascript.

Comment: Ahh thank-you, I left out that bit because I assumed it was just to tell you if your browser is supported or not. Silly me :P